# C# data extraction doesn't output the result

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I am trying to extract the data from a large XML files and insert the corresponding data to SQL table and generate report. The code basically traverses through the entire XML document and should extract the data from  the individual nodes that ends with BOs.

I am using a stored SQL procedure that will eventually group the required data from the few different tables and then insert into final table called **Report**.

But I am struck in situation where, when I run the C# code and stored procedure the table doesn't display any result. There is no data getting inserted into the SQL tables. This is typically my first dot net project and getting used to C# coding. I am trying to execute and take over my colleagues project since he is assigned to different project working offshore.

Any help on this would be much appreciated !!!  And I apologize upfront if my code example is a bit long.

```
public bool SaveNode(XmlNode Node, string proposalnumber, string quotenumber, string objectid)
            {
                StringBuilder strProposalBO = new StringBuilder();// 1
                StringBuilder strQuoteBO = new StringBuilder(); // 2
                StringBuilder strPremiumComponentBO = new StringBuilder(); // 3
                StringBuilder strPremiumDetailBO = new StringBuilder(); // 4
                StringBuilder strProductComponentBO = new StringBuilder(); // 5
                StringBuilder strRoleBO = new StringBuilder(); // 6
                StringBuilder strFormBO = new StringBuilder(); // 7
                StringBuilder strTextBO = new StringBuilder(); // 8
                StringBuilder strRiskBO = new StringBuilder(); // 9
                StringBuilder strPropertyBO = new StringBuilder(); // 10
                string acronym = "";
                Dictionary<string, string> strValues = setNodeValues(Node, proposalnumber, quotenumber, objectid);


                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "proposalboadaptable")
                {
                    strProposalBO.Append(String.Format("insert into proposal(node,createdate,createdby,objectidentifier,pk,proposalnumber,quotenumber,status,updatedate,updatedby,acronym,userdomain  ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}'  )"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("createdate", strValues), getstrValues("createdby", strValues), getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues)
                    , proposalnumber, quotenumber, getstrValues("status", strValues), getstrValues("updatedate", strValues), getstrValues("updatedby", strValues), acronym
                    , getstrValues("userdomain", strValues)));
                    SaveNodeData(strProposalBO);
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "quotebo")
                {
                    if (Node.SelectSingleNode("number") != null && Node.SelectSingleNode("number").InnerText == quotenumber)
                    {
                        strQuoteBO.Append(String.Format("insert into quote(node, businessevent, ischanged, number, objectidentifier, pk, productcategory, productclass, producttype, quotename,quotenumber, acronym,proposalnumber) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}')"
                        , objectid, getstrValues("businessevent", strValues), getstrValues("ischanged", strValues), getstrValues("number", strValues), getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues)
                        , getstrValues("productcategory", strValues), getstrValues("productclass", strValues), getstrValues("producttype", strValues), getstrValues("quotename", strValues)
                        , quotenumber, getstrValues("acronym", strValues), proposalnumber));
                        SaveNodeData(strQuoteBO);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;//if different quote number found
                    }
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "premiumcomponentbo")
                {
                    strPremiumComponentBO.Append(String.Format("insert into premiumcomponent(node, displayorder, inputoutputindicator, objectidentifier, pk, premiumcomponentcategory, premiumcomponentclass, premiumcomponentdatatype, premiumcomponenttype, quotenumber, acronym, proposalnumber ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("displayorder", strValues), getstrValues("inputoutputindicator", strValues), getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("pk", strValues), getstrValues("premiumcomponentcategory", strValues), getstrValues("premiumcomponentclass", strValues), getstrValues("premiumcomponentdatatype", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("premiumcomponenttype", strValues), quotenumber, getstrValues("acronym", strValues), proposalnumber));
                    SaveNodeData(strPremiumComponentBO);
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "premiumdetailbo")
                {
                    strPremiumDetailBO.Append(String.Format("insert into premiumdetail(node, displayorder, doublevalue, keyvalue, objectidentifier, pk, premiumdetailcategory, premiumdetailclass, premiumdetaildatatype, premiumdetailtype, unitofmeasurement, quotenumber , acronym, proposalnumber) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("displayorder", strValues), getstrValues("doublevalue", strValues), getstrValues("keyvalue", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues), getstrValues("premiumdetailcategory", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("premiumdetailclass", strValues), getstrValues("premiumdetaildatatype", strValues), getstrValues("premiumdetailtype", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("unitofmeasurement", strValues), quotenumber, getstrValues("acronym", strValues), proposalnumber));
                    SaveNodeData(strPremiumDetailBO);
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "productcomponentbo")
                {
                    strProductComponentBO.Append(String.Format("insert into productcomponent(node, categoryoverride, displayorder, helptext, ischanged, isselected, labeloverride, maximumcardinality, minimumcardinality, objectidentifier, pk, productcomponentcategory, productcomponentclass, productcomponentdatatype, productcomponenttype,quotenumber,acronym , proposalnumber ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("categoryoverride", strValues), getstrValues("displayorder", strValues), getstrValues("helptext", strValues), getstrValues("ischanged", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("isselected", strValues), getstrValues("labeloverride", strValues), getstrValues("maximumcardinality", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("minimumcardinality", strValues), getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues), getstrValues("productcomponentcategory", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("productcomponentclass", strValues), getstrValues("productcomponentdatatype", strValues), getstrValues("productcomponenttype", strValues)
                    , quotenumber, getstrValues("acronym", strValues), proposalnumber));
                    SaveNodeData(strProductComponentBO);
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "rolebos")
                {
                    strRoleBO.Append(String.Format("insert into rolebo(node,createdate,createdby,objectidentifier,pk,proposalnumber,quotenumber,status,updatedate,updatedby,userdomain ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("createdate", strValues), getstrValues("createdby", strValues), getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("proposalnumber", strValues), getstrValues("quotenumber", strValues), getstrValues("status", strValues), getstrValues("updatedate", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("updatedby", strValues), getstrValues("userdomain", strValues)));
                    SaveNodeData(strRoleBO);
                }


                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "formbo")
                {
                    strFormBO.Append(String.Format("insert into form(node, category, edition, formCategory, formClass, formName, formOrder, formType, formURL, isSelected, objectidentifier, pk ,quotenumber, proposalnumber , acronym ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("category", strValues), getstrValues("edition", strValues), getstrValues("formcategory", strValues), getstrValues("formclass", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("formname", strValues), getstrValues("formorder", strValues), getstrValues("formtype", strValues), getstrValues("formurl", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("isselected", strValues), getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues), quotenumber, proposalnumber, getstrValues("acronym", strValues)));
                    SaveNodeData(strFormBO);
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "textbo")
                {
                    strTextBO.Append(String.Format("insert into text(node,createdate,createdby,objectidentifier,pk,proposalnumber,quotenumber,status,updatedate,updatedby,userdomain ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("createdate", strValues), getstrValues("createdby", strValues), getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("proposalnumber", strValues), getstrValues("quotenumber", strValues), getstrValues("status", strValues), getstrValues("updatedate", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("updatedby", strValues), getstrValues("userdomain", strValues)));
                    SaveNodeData(strTextBO);
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "riskbo")
                {
                    strRiskBO.Append(String.Format("insert into risk(node, ischanged, labeloverride, maximumcardinality, minimumcardinality, objectidentifier, pk, riskcategory, riskclass, risktype ,quotenumber, proposalnumber, acronym) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("ischanged", strValues), getstrValues("labeloverride", strValues), getstrValues("maximumcardinality", strValues), getstrValues("minimumcardinality", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues), getstrValues("riskcategory", strValues), getstrValues("riskclass", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("risktype", strValues), quotenumber, proposalnumber, getstrValues("acronym", strValues)));
                    SaveNodeData(strRiskBO);
                }

                if (Node.Name.ToLower() == "propertybo")
                {
                    strPropertyBO.Append(String.Format("insert into property(node, categoryoverride, decimalplaces, displayorder , helptext, ischanged, keyvalue, labeloverride, objectidentifier, pk, propertycategory, propertyclass, propertydatatype, propertytype, stringvalue, unitofmeasurement, widget, widgetheightunits, widgetwidthunits,quotenumber, proposalnumber, datevalue, doublevalue, acronym) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}','{19}','{20}','{21}','{22}','{23}')"
                    , objectid, getstrValues("categoryoverride", strValues), getstrValues("decimalplaces", strValues), getstrValues("displayorder", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("helptext", strValues), getstrValues("ischanged", strValues), getstrValues("keyvalue", strValues), getstrValues("labeloverride", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("objectidentifier", strValues), getstrValues("pk", strValues), getstrValues("propertycategory", strValues), getstrValues("propertyclass", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("propertydatatype", strValues), getstrValues("propertytype", strValues), getstrValues("stringvalue", strValues), getstrValues("unitofmeasurement", strValues)
                    , getstrValues("widget", strValues), getstrValues("widgetheightunits", strValues), getstrValues("widgetwidthunits", strValues), quotenumber
                    , proposalnumber, getstrValues("datevalue", strValues), getstrValues("doublevalue", strValues), getstrValues("acronym", strValues)));
                    SaveNodeData(strPropertyBO);
                }

                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure the stored procedure works ?

Comment: Are the SQL statement actually called ? and if yes, could you post them here? Btw, there are quite a few code smells in this snippet. As you do not parametrize your queries, your code is susceptible to SQL injection. You are also catching Exceptions without rethrowing them.

Comment: Hynek : SQL procedure works! It successfully gets executed, but when I try to run the tables, it doesn't have have any data in it.

Comment: @Jaco : I am guessing , I won't be able to pose the SQL statements, because I already exceeded the character limit for the above question !

Comment: First, just because something executes without throwing an exception does not necessarily mean it worked. Second, it is also possible that you are not getting the data from the XML. You need to debug the code and see if you actually have the data you wish to save when calling the proc. If you pass nothing to the stored proc, guess what would be saved in the table - nothing.

Comment: please change `stringbuilderobject.Append(String.Format( .. ))` to `stringbuilderobject.AppendFormat( .. )`

Comment: @Shasti - *lets get real here* the code you posted would not compile.  We know you don't have working code -- post code that can compile.  For example the line `strTextBO.Append(String.Format("insert into AAIStex(t..));` does not have a terminating quote and is not legal SQL.

Comment: I have included the SQL statements in my code

Comment: You might re-think your approach... Why not pass the entire XML to SQL Server as Parameter and do the heavy work there? I do not see any high sophisticated logic. This should be quite easy with T-SQL alone...